# Воспроизведение медиа(АУДИО) в iframe с определенного места

Tags: html, iframe

Собственно ситуация. 
В `html` есть `iframe`. Возможно ли запустить и/или изменить место проигрывания в iframe (хочу песню запустить с 30ой секунды)?
Интересует так же скроллинг медиа.
Вариант с `<audio>` отпадает ,так как Chrome блокирует автоматическое воспроизведение.

Comment: >изменить место проигрывания в iframe - насколько мне известно, это невозможно. > Chrome блокирует автоматическое воспроизведение - есть методы(хаки) с решением данной проблемы

Comment: спасибо! но сколько не гуглил,не нашел рабочих вариантов.

Comment: т.е  интересует метод обхода блокировки autoplay?

Comment: если этим сайтом не запрещено - то с радостью ознакомлюсь с вашими предложениями.Исключительно в ознакомительных целях

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы `Google Chrome` не блокировал автовоспроизведение аудио, необходимо подгрузить `mp3` через `iframe`. После вы сможете работать с `<audio>`:

```
  <iframe src="audio.mp3" allow="autoplay"  style="display:none"></iframe>

    <audio id="audio" autoplay loop>
      <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      <source src="audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    </audio>
```